Why is it that when I try to use moto to a Bazel repository I get errors related to `_cffi_backend` being missing?
At work I'm currently working on a Bazel app/repository that contains tools for dealing with AWS. I recently created a tool that deals with some AWS resources in Python (a lambda that interacts with Cloudwatch alarms and a DynamoDB table), so to test the tool I wrote some tests using the moto testing library to mock up resources.
However, even though I think I've added moto to the necessary requirements files that Bazel uses to track and install Python dependencies, I get an error whenever I try to run the tests. Any attempt to run a test that references moto returns ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_cffi_backend'. As far as I can tell, this is a problem related to a module called cryptography that moto depends on, but most of the suggested solutions for this online suggest that you ought to reinstall cryptography, cffi, etc., which for obvious reasons doesn't really make sense in Bazel. (For what it's worth, I HAVE tried bazel clean several times and then rerunning the tests afterwards, to no avail.)
Here's the relevant section in the WORKSPACE file.
load("@rules_python//python:pip.bzl", "pip_parse")
pip_parse(
   name = "python_deps",
   requirements_lock = "//team_repo/libs/python:requirements.txt",
)

requirements.txt is built by pip-compile stc/libs/python/requirements.in, which in turn consists only of boto, coverage, aws-xray-sdk, and moto (the only module that seems to produce errors when called.)
Bazel is 6.4.0, and our Python version as specified in WORKSPACE is 3.11 (if relevant, this is all running on MacOS.) It's not really practical to dispense with Bazel entirely; any tips on resolving this problem are greatly appreciated.

Hmmm... at a high level I can't reproduce this. I am on Bazel 7.1, python 3.11 and have created a simple test file that imports Moto, and am also using a requirements file built by pip_parse
